# Trouble with delimiters, pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm exporting data from a thermal imaging camera and having a hard time reading it in.

In the SmartView software, there's an option to export it as a .csv. Unfortunately, when I do that, I get a .csv with the data all in the first column - for instance, this is A7:

```
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,
```

If I open Excel and then import the data, select comma delimited, it's fine. I would like to skip this step and directly read it into Pandas.

After trying many things, I've arrived at this, which works for the long manual way:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pathname, item), delimiter = None, engine = 'python', skiprows = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

And yes, I tried delimiter = ','. I tried sniffing the file.

Is there some way to read this in directly with pandas instead of opening Excel, importing each file and going through that wizard, saving the file with the new name, and then running my program to read it in?

Here's my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myprogram.py", line 56, in <module>
    new_df = import_df()
  File "myprogram.py", line 34, in import_df
    skiprows = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1147, in _make_engine
    self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2310, in __init__
    ) = self._infer_columns()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2593, in _infer_columns
    line = self._buffered_line()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2776, in _buffered_line
    return self._next_line()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2870, in _next_line
    next(self.data)
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

As @juanpa said, it's apparently not the delimiter, so I tried the encoding:

```
    new_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pathname, item), encoding='utf-16', delimiter = ',',
                     skiprows = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f


 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1917, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 735, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 937, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2124, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
  File "C:\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 504, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\encodings\utf_16.py", line 141, in decode
    raise UnicodeError("UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM")
UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM
```

And when I tried to solve that by telling it -be or -le:

```
 File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 545, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

ETA

Cut and pasted from review in PyCharm:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 
1   89.5    89.6    89.3    89.2    89.4    89.4    89.1    89.0    89.0    88.6    88.7    88.7    88.4    88.3    88.3    88.5    88.5    89.7    90.6    88.5    87.5    87.6    87.9    87.9    88.0    87.9    88.0    88.8    91.6    90.7    87.8    87.6    87.9    87.6    87.8    87.5    87.7    87.7    87.6    87.8    87.9    87.6    87.9    87.7    87.9    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.6    87.5    87.6    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.8    87.7    87.7    87.9    88.0    88.3    88.1    88.2    88.5    88.5    88.6    88.5    88.5    88.7    88.7    88.5    88.4    88.4    88.5    88.4    88.2    88.1    88.1    87.9    87.6    87.3    87.0    86.9    86.8    86.6    86.7    86.2    86.6    86.2    87.9    87.7    86.9    88.9    88.5    86.4    85.8    87.1    87.2    85.8    86.0    86.0    85.6    85.6    85.8    85.8    86.3    89.9    90.0    89.3    87.8    85.8    85.5    85.4    85.5    85.8    85.9    85.7    85.8    85.9    85.9    85.9    86.2    86.0    86.0    85.8    85.9    86.3    85.9    86.1    86.0    86.1    85.9    85.8    85.8    85.7    85.9    85.7    85.8    85.7    85.7    85.8    85.6    85.7    85.8    86.0    87.8    86.0    85.7    85.9    86.0    85.6    85.6    85.5    85.7    85.5    85.6    85.3    85.2    85.5    85.2    85.4    85.0    85.3    84.9    84.8    84.5    84.7    84.6    84.6    84.8    84.9    86.7    88.0    87.8    89.7    90.0    89.0    86.2    85.1    85.7    86.8    87.5    86.9    87.4    90.2    90.2    90.5    89.3    87.1    86.4    86.0    86.2    86.5    86.8    88.2    94.0    110.0   137.9   164.5   170.9   167.4   156.5   128.4   98.7    89.0    87.8    87.6    87.8    87.8    87.8    87.7    87.8    87.8    87.7    88.1    88.0    88.1    88.7    89.0    90.9    97.0    112.7   121.2   113.3   105.3   96.8    90.9    89.5    89.3    89.8    89.3    90.0    89.7    89.9    90.1    90.4    90.4    90.6    90.5    90.5    90.7    90.5    90.6    90.3    90.1    89.7    89.7    89.4    89.1    88.9    88.8    90.6    93.2    90.4    88.2    88.0    88.7    92.7    93.6    88.7    87.7    87.6    87.7    87.5    87.6    87.7    87.6    87.9    87.8    87.7    87.4    87.4    87.5    87.6    87.4    87.6    90.0    92.8    91.6    89.0    88.6    88.8    89.1    89.2    89.8    90.2    90.1    89.9    92.3    96.0    96.9    96.8    97.1    97.2    97.0    96.5    96.9    96.6    94.6    90.0    89.1    88.8    89.1    88.9    89.0    89.0    89.0    89.0    89.0    88.7    88.8    88.7    88.5    88.5    88.7    88.6    88.6    88.4    88.6    
2   89.6    89.6    89.5    89.4    89.4    89.5    89.2    89.4    89.3    89.0    88.8    88.8    88.7    88.5    88.4    88.3    88.2    89.9    90.7    88.6    87.8    87.7    87.8    88.0    88.0    88.0    88.1    88.6    91.6    90.6    87.6    87.5    87.6    87.8    87.7    87.6    87.6    87.8    87.8    87.7    87.7    87.6    87.8    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.8    87.8    87.9    87.7    87.7    87.9    88.0    88.0    88.1    88.1    88.2    88.2    88.5    88.3    88.4    88.4    88.5    88.7    88.4    88.5    88.4    88.5    88.4    88.2    88.0    87.9    88.1    87.6    87.2    87.2    87.1    86.6    86.5    86.4    86.4    86.4    87.8    87.9    86.8    87.7    89.1    87.0    85.9    85.9    87.7    86.4    85.8    85.6    85.6    85.7    85.6    85.6    85.8    85.8    87.6    88.9    90.0    89.3    85.8    85.3    85.5    85.4    85.6    85.8    85.8    85.8    86.0    86.0    85.8    86.1    86.1    85.9    85.9    86.0    86.2    85.9    86.0    85.9    86.0    85.9    85.8    85.9    85.8    85.8    85.7    85.8    85.7    85.6    85.7    85.6    85.6    85.7    86.0    87.7    86.1    85.8    85.8    85.8    85.5    85.5    85.6    85.5    85.5    85.5    85.3    85.3    85.4    85.2    85.3    85.0    85.1    85.0    84.8    84.6    84.6    84.6    84.6    84.9    85.9    87.0    87.7    88.6    89.6    89.4    87.5    85.6    85.0    85.3    86.0    86.4    86.2    86.5    89.1    90.0    90.3    89.9    88.3    87.2    86.2    86.3    86.6    87.0    90.7    104.8   119.1   135.1   157.2   163.4   159.5   145.8   115.6   93.8    88.4    87.8    87.8    87.8    87.9    88.1    88.0    88.0    88.0    88.1    88.1    88.0    88.6    89.6    93.3    108.4   122.4   119.0   107.3   104.8   115.0   112.6   95.8    91.3    89.8    89.4    89.5    89.8    89.8    90.0    90.1    90.3    90.5    90.7    90.5    90.7    90.7    90.7    90.5    90.4    90.1    89.7    89.6    89.4    89.1    89.0    88.8    90.5    93.3    90.5    88.2    88.0    89.2    93.8    92.6    88.1    87.8    87.6    87.7    87.6    87.4    87.6    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.6    87.4    87.4    87.2    87.6    87.4    87.6    89.6    93.2    91.9    88.4    87.6    87.7    88.1    88.1    88.0    88.1    88.1    88.8    90.4    92.6    93.9    94.9    95.4    93.9    95.9    96.2    96.5    96.2    94.0    91.0    89.6    89.7    89.7    89.6    90.1    90.0    89.9    89.8    89.5    89.3    89.3    89.2    89.0    89.0    88.9    88.8    88.8    88.7    88.8    
3   89.8    89.6    89.6    89.4    89.4    89.4    89.3    89.2    88.9    88.9    88.8    88.8    88.5    88.4    88.2    88.3    88.6    90.0    90.8    88.7    87.7    87.8    87.9    88.1    88.1    88.0    88.3    89.1    91.8    90.7    87.8    87.7    87.8    87.9    87.8    87.6    87.7    87.9    87.8    87.6    87.5    87.9    87.8    87.7    87.8    87.6    87.7    87.7    87.7    87.8    87.8    87.7    88.0    87.8    87.8    87.6    87.7    87.7    88.0    88.0    88.1    88.2    88.2    88.2    88.2    88.2    88.3    88.3    88.3    88.4    88.6    88.4    88.5    88.4    88.2    88.0    87.8    87.9    87.8    87.6    87.6    87.4    87.3    87.2    86.9    86.7    86.6    86.5    86.9    88.2    86.9    87.2    88.9    88.3    86.0    85.9    86.1    88.0    85.9    85.8    85.7    85.5    85.7    85.7    85.8    85.7    85.6    86.1    88.7    88.7    90.5    87.3    85.4    85.3    85.3    85.6    85.7    85.7    85.8    86.0    85.8    85.9    85.9    86.1    86.0    85.8    85.9    86.0    85.9    85.9    85.9    85.7    85.8    85.9    86.0    85.8    85.9    85.9    85.7    85.5    85.5    85.6    85.5    85.4    85.6    85.8    87.6    86.7    85.8    85.7    85.6    85.5    85.5    85.5    85.4    85.4    85.3    85.3    85.3    85.4    85.3    85.2    85.0    85.0    84.9    84.7    84.7    84.8    84.5    84.9    86.5    87.3    87.2    89.0    89.4    88.8    86.3    84.9    84.9    84.9    85.0    85.1    85.2    85.4    85.5    86.8    89.4    89.3    90.2    90.5    89.4    87.9    86.7    86.7    88.8    102.6   119.8   105.2   99.4    112.6   131.1   136.5   121.0   94.4    88.2    87.7    87.7    88.0    88.3    89.0    89.2    89.2    88.9    88.9    89.2    88.9    89.0    89.9    96.1    114.3   124.8   109.1   94.3    90.1    91.5    104.7   118.5   106.7   93.4    90.5    89.9    89.8    89.8    90.1    90.3    90.4    90.5    90.7    90.8    90.6    90.7    90.8    90.7    90.7    90.3    90.2    90.0    89.7    89.4    89.0    89.1    88.9    90.0    93.0    91.0    88.3    88.2    90.5    94.3    91.1    88.1    87.7    87.5    87.6    87.6    87.6    87.6    87.6    87.8    87.9    87.7    87.4    87.5    87.7    87.6    87.5    87.6    90.1    93.5    92.9    89.2    87.8    88.0    88.0    87.9    87.9    88.0    88.0    88.3    88.3    88.7    88.8    89.2    89.2    89.0    89.6    90.5    91.0    91.4    90.2    89.1    89.0    89.4    89.5    89.8    89.6    89.6    89.6    89.4    89.4    89.7    89.8    89.5    89.4    89.7    89.4    89.4    89.2    89.2    89.2
```

Comment: I don't know why you think the problem is the delimiter, `pandas.read_csv` can definitely handle a comma delimiter. Don't use `engine='python'`, and try passing it `encoding='utf-16'`

Comment: new error = progress

Comment: You should use a text editor, e.g. VS Code, to view the first few lines of the csv.  I suspect the data is wrapped between quotes `""`.

Comment: I just dumped it into PyCharm and I didn't find any. Could it be that the first point should be blank?

Answer (score 0):

Based on you excerpt from *PyCharm*, it looks like you had individual
columns separated with either a *Tab* or a sequence of **spaces**.

So maybe you should pass *sep=r'[\t ]+'* (and *engine='python'* to
avoid a warning presented otherwise).

I copied you excerpt, creating a string variable:

```
txt = '''
1   2   3   4   5   6 ...
89.5    89.6    89.3  ...
89.6    89.6    89.5  ...
89.8    89.6    89.6  ...
'''
```

Then I executed:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), skiprows=1, sep=r'[\t ]+', engine='python')
```

getting a DataFrame with 3 rows and 320 columns, without any error.

In your case, change *skiprows* to the actual number of initial lines
to skip (instead of a list of consecutive numbers). This is easier to read.

Comment: I'm now getting a parser error...and I don't know if it was my copy and paste mistake or not, but there should be a space in front of the "1", because the column names are really the x coordinates and the unnamed column before the data is y coordinates...i.e., I think your solution for the spacing worked a little too well...

Comment: Note that copying text from your excerpt, I deleted in each row 4 initial characters (the index column). So my *txt* variable contains only data columns. Note also that in my answer I put "..." instead of the rest of the actual line. And the last row contains 3 **apostrophes** (not dots).